# Getting key out off array within function Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
function uploadify()
 {
  $file = $this->input->post('filearray');
  $data['json'] = json_decode($file);



  print_r($data);

  $name = $this->$json->{'file_name'};

  echo $name;

        $this->files->add($name);

  $this->load->view('uploadify',$data);
 }
```

> Array ( [json] => stdClass Object (
>   [file_name] => footer-icpn246.jpg
>   [real_name] => footer-icpn2.jpg
>   [file_ext] => .jpg [file_size] => 1.75
>   [file_path] =>
>   /home/codeig/public_html/files/footer-icpn246.jpg
>   [file_temp] =>
>   /home/codeig/tmp/php8gFyPG ) )

Above is the output from print_r($data);

How would i then pull the key off file name out off this array??? I have tried.

```
$name = $this->$json->{'file_name'};

$name = $this->json->[file_name];
```

and many more combinations any help please.

echo $name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do in this way

```
$file = $this->input->post('filearray');
        $json = json_decode($file);

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        //Add media to DB
        $data= array(
            'file_name' => $json->{'file_name'}, 
            'file_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'file_type' => $json->{'file_ext'}, 
            'file_size' => $json->{'file_size'},
            'user_id' => $user_id);
```

this link may help you http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/109751/P90/

Answer (score 0):

If that is the output of `print_r($data)` you must refer to $data not to $this. Anyway as you can see from the result of print_r the variable is an array, "json" is an index of that array that contains an object with the file_name property, so you must use:

```
$data["json"]->file_name
```